# Duplicating GCP Project in Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

On GCP Compute Engine, I have a Project A with several VMs running. I am not using App Engine.

How can I duplicate or make an exact copy of Project A into a second Project B (having the same VMs config and all its source and data files in Project A) thus resulting in two exact Projects?

I can't seem to find a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no "copy project" internal tool to perform such a task. Speaking about VMs,the fastest way to move existing VM would be by making disk images and creating new instances at the new project using the image from your old project using the "-image-project IMAGE_PROJECT" flag.

Comment: Hi Alessio, thank you for your reply answer. I have tried out imaging the VMs and transferred them to another project.Everything looks the same except when I click the VM's SSH, the Command window launched has a slightly different startup (e.g. the terminal logo of Bitnami does not show in the new imaged VMs as they do in the original VMs).

Comment: I read that the "-image-project IMAGE_PROJECT" flag is optional. I tried creating images with both options - stating and not stating this flag. Can't see any differences in both situations. Thank you very much for your assistance on this issue.

Comment: Example of cloning: project-A -------> Project-B , from the A you create some images base on your running machine then from the project B you can run the following command: gcloud compute instances create INSTANCE_NAMES [INSTANCE_NAMES …]  --image [your custom image from A]  --image-project project-B               For more details have a look at this link https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/sharing-images-across-projects